# Emploi de « chez » dans une précaution d'emploi

Tags: usage, prépositions, santé-et-médecine

> Ne pas utiliser chez l'enfant de 5 ans et moins.

(Précautions d'emploi d'un dentifrice. )

Bien que je comprenne le sens, je me demande quelle fonction de *chez* permet son emploi dans ce contexte.

Comment: Lire § C.2. in TLF : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chez (*le groupe prép. désigne une classe d'êtres dont on décrit les traits ou les comportements spécifiques*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cet usage de *chez* est très courant dans ce style de notice d'emploi. C'est même la tournure [obligatoire](https://www.vidal.fr/actualites/22262/grossesse_les_boites_de_medicaments_a_risque_arborent_le_pictogramme_femmes_enceintes/) depuis 2017 pour les médicaments présentant un risque pour les femmes enceintes :

L'article 1 de [l'arrêté du 5 mai 2017](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/eli/arrete/2017/5/5/AFSP1713086A/jo) du Journal officiel relatif à l'apposition d'un pictogramme sur le conditionnement extérieur de certains médicaments ou produits dit :

> ...
>   En dessous de ce pictogramme, figure le message suivant : « **Ne pas utiliser chez [mentionner les personnes concernées]** sauf en l'absence d'alternative thérapeutique ».
>   ...

*Chez*, qui signifie étymologiquement *dans la maison de*, signifie ici que l'avertissement s'adresse à un groupe d'individus ayant quelque chose en commun.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. L'ayant choisie maintenant je me demande pourquoi pas "Ne pas permettre l'utilisation aux enfants de moins de cinq ans."

Comment: Parce que c'est plus lourd et moins directif. *Ne pas permettre l'utilisation aux* fait penser à une punition ou laisse entendre que l'adulte a le choix d'interdire ou pas alors que *Ne pas utiliser chez* est un ordre catégorique.

Answer (score 3):

Cet usage, qui me semble caduc, se rapproche le plus de l'usage suivant dont il est fait mention dans le TLFi;

> Avec des plur., des coll. ou des sing. de sens générique; le groupe prép. désigne une classe d'êtres dont on décrit les traits ou les comportements spécifiques

J'ajouterai à cette définition les compléments suivants: ou les réactions physiologiques, psychologiques.

exemples

> - Chez l'enfant il y a des signes précoces de cette maladie.
> - C'est chez l'enfant que l'on ne peut pas appliquer une thérapie idéale.

Il semble probable que l'usage résulte d'un mauvais calque sur l'usage médical auquel je fais référence, ce calque étant fondé sur la considération que le dentifrice serait un médicament, ce que ce n'est pas.

Il semble que quelque chose comme «  Ne pas permettre l'utilisation aux enfants de moins de cinq ans » aurait été préférable. Cependant, si un avis majoritaire parmi des responsables linguistiques était la conclusion que l'extension que ce nouvel usage représente constitue un apport au langage tout en préservant une certaine harmonie, pourquoi ne pas le légitimer? Pour ma part, d'après l'habitude  que j'ai du langage je trouve cet usage désagréable, mais cela pourrait n'être que le résultat de préjugés à priori, avant d'avoir considéré un raisonnement de légitimation.

Addition après lecture d'une [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/31937/17649) à cette même question

Il faudra après tout se faire à l'idée que la formulation en question est légitime; l'avis de responsables linguistiques auquel je réfère est manifesté explicitement dans la [référence](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/eli/arrete/2017/5/5/AFSP1713086A/jo) que fournit la réponse ( l'arrêté du 5 mai 2017).

Seconde addition

Aprés réflexion je joint à la présente réponse une petite étude que j'ai faite et qui semble éclairer l'usage discuté assez profitablement (c'est une capture d'écran d'un pdf personnel).

[image]

Comment: Caduque ? Pas à ma connaissance. La dernière édition du Vidal l'utilise toujours et c'est je crois toujours le cas des notices pharmaceutiques contemporaines.

Comment: @aCOSwt « Caduque » en ce sens que ce n'est  pas un emploi idiomatique, mais pas plus; dans Vidal il n'est question que médicaments pas de dentifrice; est-ce que après une extension légère de l'idée dans la précaution « Moutarde forte - ne pas permettre chez l'enfant de moins de cinq ans » vous trouveriez toujours que l'usage est idiomatique?

Comment: auquel cas, je dirais que c'est la recommandation qui est caduque. Qui n'a plus lieu d'être. Pas l'usage.

Comment: @aCOSwt L'association d'une unité lexicale (chez l'enfant) à un contexte (utilisateur qu'est l'enfant) ne constituerait donc pas un usage?

Comment: Si absolument et cet *usage*-là (*"association d'une..."*) n'est quant à lui pas caduc puisque toujours repris dans le cadre d'autres produits.

Comment: @aCOSwt Je ne saisis pas ce dont il est question dans cette critique; de plus lorsque je considère la caducité de la précaution je n'arrive pas à la même conclusion : la précaution (ne pas laisser utilliser) qu'elle soit formulée en langage qui convienne ou non, reste ce qu'elle est un avis, on l'espère, pertinent, du fournisseur de dentifrice; l'usage, selon mon point de vue -- cela me semble très élémentaire -- n'est qu'un des ingrédients dans la formulation (le choix de mots); on doit pouvoir dire que le choix de mots est caduc pour n'employer que ce mot à faute d'un mot plus exact.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas pourquoi ce blocage sur le dentifrice. Le dentifrice est sans aucun doute un produit de santé, d'hygiène bucco-dentaire. Il  peut être vendu en pharmacie et en parapharmacie. Il peut contenir des éléments à usage thérapeutique, essentiellement des composés fluorés qui pourraient avoir un effet nocif sur les jeunes enfants susceptibles de l'avaler au lieu de le recracher après usage. Cette précaution d'emploi à caractère médical me semble donc parfaitement en phase avec du dentifrice. Je n'ai en revanche jamais vu de moutarde, forte ou pas, en pharmacie ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre L'arrêté ne date que de un an et demi  et auparavant, alors que l'usage n'était pas précisé (médicament **et produit**) l'usage établi de « chez » était situé dans le domaine des avis médicaux ou scientifiques à caractère médical. Je n'ai jamais trouvé cet usage sur les tubes de dentifrice courants ni sur des emballages de *produits* qui ne sont pas des médicaments. On ne dit  pas « N'utilisez pas ces méthodes chez l'enfant de cours moyen 1. »  mais vraiment « N'utilisez pas ces méthodes **avec** l'enfant de cours moyen 1. ».

Comment: Oui, je suis bien d'accord avec le fait que ce n'est pas utilisé dans des contextes non médicaux mais on parle ici des risques de fluorose due à l'absorption de dentifrice par de jeunes enfants connus depuis au moins une vingtaine d'années. Une demande d'indication de précautions d'usage pour les jeunes enfants sur les dentifrices a été effectuée [en 2001 auprès de la Commission européenne par l'Agence française de sécurité sanitaire et des produits de santé](https://ansm.sante.fr/var/ansm_site/storage/original/application/59dd83519c88dd558327e9b9b1d8d2f9.pdf).

Comment: @jlliagre Dans ce cas assez particulier et surtout depuis l'arrêté la « légimitivité» de l'usage ne se discute que difficilement; c'est ce que je reconnais dans ma réponse (l'addition). « Pas utilisé dans les contextes non médicaux » n'est pas exactement ce que je perçois; je joint une analyse complémentaire à ma réponse dans le but de rendre plus précise la définition du dictionnaire, ce qui inclut la notion plus compréhensive qu'il me semble devrait être retenue de cet usage.

Comment: @user168676 Merci pour ta réponse. À vrai dire je ne peux pas suivre toute la réponse et les commentaires associées. Pour que comprenne, pensez-vous que cet usage n'est pas correct ? Cet emploi est-il une sorte de néologisme ?

Comment: @dimitris Ce serait plus ou moins un néologisme, mais au vu de l'arrêté au journal officiel (voir les réponses ci-dessus et l'arrêté dont il est question), lequel mentionne sans ambigüité le terme « produit » en plus du terme bien établi « médicament » l'usage particulier qui nous concerne acquiert un indéniable degré de légitimité, ce qui n'en fait pas un usage sacré : je crois que la France a une tradition de pratiques linguistiques qui ont été introduites par ses administrations et qui ont été par la suite décriées publiquement, en particulier par des personnages comme des chansonniers.